# Generate random number X where X % Y = 0

Tags: python, random

I am interested in only a selection of random number ,
in this case  `X % 5 == 0`.

```
from random import randint
num = randint(5,15000) #Inclusive
while not (num % 5 == 0):
    num = randint(5,15000)
print num
```

here is what I have so far, but this does not seem like it's very pythonic.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about generate a random int `r` in the range of 1 to `MAX / Y` and use `r * Y`?

E.g.,

```
from random import randint
num = randint(1,15000 / 5) * 5
print num
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
MAX = 15000
n = 5
print n * random.randint(1, MAX / n)
```